# How can I get the category name of a web page if this web page has subcategories?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am getting the category name with the next code:

```
 $categories = get_the_category();
 $category = $categories[0]->name;
```

This is working correctly in a web page with just one category:

http://localhost:8888/wordpress/category**/incubate/**

But the problem is when I have a subcategory:

http://localhost:8888/wordpress/category**/incubate/business-ops/**

(My permanent links: localhost:8888/wordpress//%category%/%postname%/)

This is my main layout:

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying archive pages
*
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package finTechHubTheme
 */



$categories = get_the_category();
$category = $categories[0]->name;

get_header(); ?>


// I want to use the parent category here.


<?php
//get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: whats the error you get?

Comment: Can you post the structure of a category with subcategories?

Comment: You do know you can't share localhost links with us right?

Comment: `var_dump($categories)` on your subcategory page, and you will see where is the problem

Comment: Hey there sorry these are the results to var_dump:    

var_dump($categories);  
result: array(0) { }  

var_dump($subcategory);  
result: NULL    

Yes I know that you cannot to see my web page on local host, I have added that because I think is important see the URL structure.    


My issues with the php debugger are the next:     

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ...  
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...

Comment: The problem is not with the code itself, you need to provide more details.